# Passing (form1) Datagridview "ID" cell content to (form2) in textbox with the click of button

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a question regarding to my problem on how to pass the value from datagridview or selected ID by the user then with a click of the button the Selected ID in Datagridview should pass into the other form in textbox and show. This is what I want to happen. Because I want to use the ID from form 1 to form 2 for my child database.
Actually my content in datagridview is from mysql as my database and load data automatically when it runs. If anyone could help me then

```vb
Public Class frmCurriculumCourses
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim ConnectionString As String = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;database=dbgradeinquiry;password=12345;"

    Sub LoadData()

        con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        con.Open()

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT * from tblcurriculumcourses"
        End With
        dt = New DataTable
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        con.Dispose()
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Sub

 Private Sub frmCurriculum_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub

 Private Sub btnViewCourses_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewCourses.Click
        'This is the button that im going to use for passing the selected ID from datagridview(form1) to textbox(form2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You just need a method or property on the second form - a means to pass data: `Public Sub LoadData(theID As Int32)`.  then send the data thru that method: `myForm2Instance.LoadData(theId)`.

Comment: Are you expert in VB.net Sir?

Comment: What Plutonix suggested is the best solution. No need for a module or to make a control on the form public. The sub method is the cleanest in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to pass the column 1 values of the Selected Row in Datagridview, then use following code,

```
Private Sub btnViewCourses_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewCourses.Click
  Form2.show()
  Form2.TextBox1.Text=DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString 
End Sub
```

or use this following command,

```
DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
```

Comment: That gives me an error with your first suggested Sir.

Comment: The second one nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and a global variable:

```
Public Module GlobalVariables
Public cellID As String
End Module
```

Add this code to the btnViewCourses button (form1):

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = cellID
```

Add this piece of code to your Form1 class:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
cellID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
End Sub
```

or click on datagridview > events > CellClick and add (same as above):

```
cellID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
```

This code will pass a SELECTED **SINGLE** value.
How to use: Show form2 (don't forget), select a cell in datagridview with elft click, press the button.

Make sure you have a textbox named textbox2 in your form2. If you want to change the name do it and change the name in *Form2.**TextBox1**.Text = cellID*

If you want to pass the whole column (to a multiline textbox or a new datagridview) then store values one by one into the public variable or make your public variable an array. I would go with one by one.

Change your public variable from String to Integer if you are using integer numbers for IDs (you should).

Comment: Hi, I dont have an idea on how to do that. COuld you show it to me the full code that I want to happen. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this work to you sir? I have tried and added form2.Show in btnViewCourses but no luck. :(

Comment: maybe it needs a connection from database first, because my data in datagridview cames from loaded database.

Comment: Yes it works. Show form2 when loading form1 and try again. Don't forget to click on a cell which is not empty. Add the public module outside you class. Next time include an error when commenting.

Comment: Of course it needs. How do you populate your rows if you have no data? Try populating your datagridview by manually and try the code I posted.

Comment: Ohh.. Sorry Sir. Already followed your instructions like public module. I populated via the Sub LoadData. Adding data from the database and populate it to datagridview.

Comment: Actually this is part of my thesis. hahaha.. Hope you could help me

Comment: What is your exact problem? Please add all of your info in one comment.

Comment: Private Sub btnViewCourses_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewCourses.Click
        Dim NEWFORM As New frmCurriculumCourses
        NEWFORM.txtCurriculumCourseID.Text = SelectedID
        NEWFORM.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        SelectedID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
        
    End Sub

It works now but gives me a 0 value in textbox

Comment: Create a new form from project > add windows forms. Make sure you have changed the variable name in module too. If the error persist, create a new project and try my code. If it works add it piece by piece in your code. Do it and reply. If it will not work I post my whole code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help but I solve my problem now in other way and simple code. Thanks :)